# How to pass a numpy variable to python script

Tags: python, numpy

I have two script, one for generate data.

main.py

```
import numpy as np
import os
data = np.array([[1,2,3,4],dtype=np.float32)
os.system("python draw.py "+data.tostring())
```

Another one for plot:

draw.py

```
import numpy as np
param = np.fromstring(sys.argv[1], dtype=np.float32)
print param
```

I just want to pass the numpy variable to another script through string,However, When I tried to use this command to run.

```
python main.py
```

I got this:

```
----> 1 os.system("python draw.py "+data.tostring())

TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str
```

I think it's because the splashes, but I don't know how to deal with it. It there any body faced this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to put them both in the same script, then you can define your plotting routine as a function in `draw.py` and then import it in `main.py`.  You should avoid invoking Python scripts externally, since Python's import mechanism is more direct and less error-prone.

`draw.py`:

```
import numpy as np

def plot(param):
    # Your plotting code here.
    print param
```

`main.py`:

```
import numpy as np
from draw import plot

data = np.array([[1,2,3,4],dtype=np.float32)
plot(data)
```